# Change font size and align to center in navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I am not able to figure out how to change the fontsize of the title of my application.I was able to change the default color of the text,however I can't locate where the font-size is located for the title.Also the title appears to the left of the navbar and I would like to align the title to center.I tried this but only the text color changed to orange.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
color: orange;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML please? It would be great if you can provide a working demo of what you have so far.

Comment: Assuming you are just using standard Bootstrap, can't you just use `.navbar`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I've put that css in every single navbar that's there in bootstrap.css file and still can't get it to work.I've cleared browser cache as well.Without using bootstrap and instyle i can get it to work.

Comment: Becuase deeper selectors are likely overriding them, share your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic `.navbar-inverse` example with `.navbar-brand` centered with the properties desired:

```css
.navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks it works,you were right that deeper selectors were overriding the style